# Electron and MLab

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, graphql, mlab

I am curious about the use of mLab with Electron. Reading [this article](https://www.techiediaries.com/electron-data-persistence/) it seems like mongo cannot be bundled into an electron application. I am wondering what that mean and if mLab would be the same thing.

Does bundling mean for mongo configs that use the db locally? I would like a solution that has an online management system that I can access if I make say a React Native application or a PWA as well as the local Electron app.

Is there something else I should be looking at instead to meet this need of data prescience. The application I am building would need to save quite a bit of data so local storage in the browser API wouldn't work for me and I really like NoSQL.

What are your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

`Mongo cannot be bundled with electron` means your electron app can only have the mongo client (mongoose for example) but not the mongo server/db itself.

If your usecase requires a lot of data to be stored locally (offline) then you may use NeoDB, PouchDB (LokiJs is popular too). They are installed as packages so can be bundled with electron app.

If accessing internet is part of your app, then you may use mLab service, requires you store or generate credentials to pack with electron to connect to mLab.

mLab is just mongo db as a service, i.e they install it for you as you access it the same way as local mongo server (but as service) instead of you hosting a server.

Recommend you to check https://docs.mlab.com/mlab-to-atlas/ if you already have data on mLab or start with Mongo Atlas instead.

mLab acquired by MongoDB Inc.
https://blog.mlab.com/2018/10/mlab-is-becoming-a-part-of-mongodb-inc/

Comment: Awesome, so because I plan on accessing the internet then I can use mongoose to access mLab?

Comment: Yes, you can use mongoose, for any mongoDB related connections. You probably should check Mongo Atlas instead, since mLab is acquired by Mongo Inc. https://blog.mlab.com/2018/10/mlab-is-becoming-a-part-of-mongodb-inc/.